# Maven: Variables are not replaced in installed and deployed POM

Tags: maven-2

We have been trying to migrate our multi-module projects to maven. I have been struggling with the maven install plugin bug "http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2971". I have written a Java program which can find and replace the expressions using my settings.xml and POM in my local repository view.

As a result all of my parent POM's are having a additional phase in the build process. What i'm doing is that i have attached a goal which will run my Java program during "validate" phase.

I think this is a not a good idea instead i would have asked individuals to run the program on their local repository on their own.

What i'm asking here is that the best way to work around the "install" plugin issue (MNG-2971).

I searched through the net but i could not locate such work around.

Comment: My first question is why do you need such things? What about ${project.version}? Or what is the problem in particular? May be you can post your pom here? On the other hand it would be problematic if variables are not replaces in POM's, cause what are the correct values? How can you reproduce the build ?

Comment: I wanted to change the version at one place hence i'm using settings.xml. What do you mean by project.version? My parent POM will be something like below and i'm using release.version all over the place including in my child POM. When i install using mvn install, the artifact is installed under the right version. But why not the POM parsed properly..?

<project .....  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
  <version>${release.version}</version>  
  <packaging>pom</packaging> 
<modules>....</modules>
...
............

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't try it because I'm not using properties from the settings.xml but the issue has a [work around](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2971?focusedCommentId=169243&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_169243) in the comments.

Comment: Yes...I saw that...Is there is any other alternate? I really want to have "something" which can run over my local repostiory right after the artifact download from my "artifactory" or when i invoke "mvn install".